# CordovaWebViewImpl security issue

Tags: cordova, webview

I am new to cordova, I just created a new project for android platform using cordova 4.0, i am debugging in android studio, when I call showWebPage, I got this error:

W/CordovaWebViewImpl﹕ Blocked (possibly sub-frame) navigation to non-allowed URL: https://xxxxxxxxxx

The html page has this security config:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://*/* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; child-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks